# Right click on an element and click on delete icon in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

Select an Element 
Right click on Element - Right click menu appears with cut,copy, delete icons
and Click on Delete icon(Note:-Delete text appears if you hover over the icon)
I am not able to inspect delete icon, because its in right click menu 
right click menu is disappearing if if i try to inspect element

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to contextclick on the element and then navigate with the arrow and return key to select and submit the delete option.

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath..."));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(elem);
actions.contextClick(elem).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
    actions.perform();
```

Comment: -------the above method works till right click but still not able to click on the Delete icon , getting element not visible      i tried below code :-                                                                                                                                      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
          WebElement button =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@id='ext-quicktips-tip-outerCt']"));
                 js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);

Comment: So why not automating with Arrow and Return Keys (just for navigation in the context menue) ?

Comment: Because right Arrow or left arrows are not working and delete is in top menu at the left , However arrow down works perfectly for other options to select.